# SuiteScript password validation allows to save a record not to equal five characters

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

A SuiteScript password validation script I've created should catch anytime a password is not exactly 5 characters long, but when I  save the record it saves without showing the alert, "password does not match", when the password is not equal to 5. How do I fix this?

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/currentRecord', 'N/search'],

function(currentRecord, search) {

    /**
     * Function to be executed after page is initialized.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.mode - The mode in which the record is being accessed (create, copy, or edit)
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function pageInit(scriptContext) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is changed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
     * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(scriptContext.fieldId));
        var objRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        if (scriptContext.fieldId === 'custrecord_cc_password'){

            var value = objRecord.getValue({
                fieldId: 'custrecord_cc_password'
            });

            if (value.match == 5) {
                //alert("OK");
                return true;
            }

            else {
                alert("Your password should be 5 digits");
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function(it is a function and not a property) is used to match string and not the length of the string.

To validate the length of string, you need to used [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property.

So in your case, replacing match with length should do the trick.

```
if (value.length === 5) {
  //alert("OK");
  return true;
}
```

However `fieldChanged` event will only be triggered when user updates the password, so to avoid this you should also implement `saveRecord` and return **false** if your validatiion does not pass like below.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define([],
  function () {

    function saveRecord(context) {
      var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;

      var password = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_cc_password' });

      if (password.length < 5) {
        // show error
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    return { saveRecord: saveRecord };
  }
);
```

Comment: Not really, I changed to ==
and its still saving the record anyway without asking "password does not match"

Comment: Your question is misleading, you wanted to match the length and not the contents. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Changed the code to if (value.length == 5). the netsuite record still saves non 5 characters passwords. How to avoid that

Comment: From your script, it seems you only have implemented `fieldChanged` event, you need to implement `saveRecord` method and return `false` if your validation fails, this method will always be triggered on record save even if password was changed before.

Comment: Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4410693749.html) out for further reading on `saveRecord` method.

Comment: could you please put the code on answer section? update it plz

Comment: updated the code. still no results. it saves the record anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your script that you changed?